# this is dangerous if i insert query in sql field

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

this is not sql injection

for example imagine user fill my form application in web form, in one field of form user write (select * from users) or write dangerous sql script and send data and everything set in my db so my record in table e.g

```
id  |  title | desc
--------------------
1   |  first | select * from users
```

how to protect it of? or generally this is dangerous?
tnx

Answer (score 5):

> this is not sql injection

This is [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

> how to protect it of? or generally this is dangerous?

since you have tagged asp.net always use Parameterized Queries.
See: [Using Parameterized Queries with the SqlDataSource (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-cs) and
[Parameterized SQL Queries in C#](http://johnhforrest.com/2010/10/parameterized-sql-queries-in-c/)

**EDIT:**
Since the OP mentioned in the comments about the usage of Entity. Following points should be considered:

[Prevent SQL injection attacks. - Entity Framework - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716760.aspx)

> LINQ to Entities injection attacks:
>
> Although query composition is possible in LINQ to Entities, it is
>   performed through the object model API. Unlike Entity SQL queries,
>   LINQ to Entities queries are not composed by using string manipulation
>   or concatenation, and they are not susceptible to traditional SQL
>   injection attacks.

Comment: no, i use entity framework 4, ef protect sql injection but this is value of some feild such as string value

Comment: @AbbasBafekr, you should have mentioned that on the question. In this case, it will be saved as a string value in the database and will not be considered dangerous

Comment: @AbbasBafekr So you're worried about if someone enters a script into your database? That won't be a problem unless for some reason you build up some non-parameterised dynamic sql based on that field - but why would you need to do that?

Comment: @Bridge i make a website and users can edit website information

Comment: @Habib i checked but you say this is injection again, i think this is not injection

Comment: @AbbasBafekr, the edit was in response to SQL injection, what you are doing currently is perfectly fine, and storing a SQL query in a text/string type field in database is fine.